# Boost SSL-Server fails with SSLv3-error

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am programming a "Terminal" in C++ to which a client can connect using SSL to encrypt the connection. I use `Boost::asio` to handle the sockets and SSL.

I am starting the SSL-Context like this:

```
boost::asio::ssl::context context_(io_service_, boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv1);
```

As you can see, I set the SSL-Version to `TLSv1`.

This are the context-options:

```
context_.set_options(boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds
                        | boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2
                        | boost::asio::ssl::context::single_dh_use);

    context_.use_certificate_chain_file("CERTS/server.crt");
    context_.use_private_key_file("CERTS/server.key", boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);
    context_.use_tmp_dh_file("CERTS/dh512.pem");
```

When I now conntect to my server with `openssl s_client -connect localhost:8000 -tls1` the handshake fails on the serverside with the error:

**"sslv3 alert handshake failure"**

Also, I noticed a strange line on the client side:

**"140030998197920:error:14082174:SSL routines:SSL3_CHECK_CERT_AND_ALGORITHM:dh key too small:s3_clnt.c:3329:"**

What does this mean? Did I make a mistake when I created the certificate? I did it exactly as described in [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452756/exception-running-boost-asio-ssl-example/8407739).

Comment: Using only `boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2` means the SSLv3 record layer can be used. You should probably OR-in `boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv3`. `boost::asio::ssl::context::single_dh_use` will crush performance. You might consider generating one, using it for an hour, generating another one, using it for an hour, etc. For the DH too small problem, see [SSL operation failed with code 1: dh key too small](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30706878/608639).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> context_.use_tmp_dh_file("CERTS/dh512.pem");
> ... dh key too small:s3_clnt.c:3329:"
> ```

You are using a DH key of only 512 bit. Such keys are considered too weak and the handshake will fail with newer versions of TLS libraries. You should better use a 2048 bit DH key instead or even better use ciphers with ECDHE.

For more details on the problem see [Logjam Attack](https://weakdh.org/).