# Boost asio handshake failed in LAN

Tags: c++, ssl, boost

I have test the Boost::asio SSL Server Client example

Server.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
public:
  session(boost::asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket> socket)
    : socket_(std::move(socket))
  {
  }

  void start()
  {
    do_handshake();
  }

private:
  void do_handshake()
  {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    socket_.async_handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::server, 
        [this, self](const boost::system::error_code& error)
        {
          if (!error)
          {
            do_read();
          }
        });
  }

  void do_read()
  {
      std::cout << "Server do_read()" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Hier bin ich noch drin!" << std::endl;
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_),
        [this, self](const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t length)
        {
        std::cout << "Server do_read() - kp" << std::endl;
          if (!ec)
          {
          std::cout << "Server do_read() - 2" << std::endl;
            do_write(length);
          }
        });
  }

  void do_write(std::size_t length)
  {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
      std::cout << "Daten = " << data_ << std::endl;
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(data_, length),
        [this, self](const boost::system::error_code& ec,
          std::size_t /*length*/)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
        std::cout << "Fehlerfrei gesendet!" << std::endl;
            do_read();
          }
        });
  }

  boost::asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket> socket_;
  char data_[1024];
};

class server
{
public:
  server(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, unsigned short port)
    : acceptor_(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port)),
      context_(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23)
  {
    context_.set_options(
        boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds
        | boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2
        | boost::asio::ssl::context::single_dh_use);
    context_.set_password_callback(std::bind(&server::get_password, this));
    context_.use_certificate_chain_file("server.crt");
    context_.use_private_key_file("server.key", boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);
    context_.use_tmp_dh_file("dh2048.pem");

    do_accept();
  }

private:
  std::string get_password() const
  {
    return "test";
  }

  void do_accept()
  {
    acceptor_.async_accept(
        [this](const boost::system::error_code& error, tcp::socket socket)
        {
          if (!error)
          {
            std::make_shared<session>(
                boost::asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket>(
                  std::move(socket), context_))->start();
          }

          do_accept();
        });
  }

  tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
  boost::asio::ssl::context context_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    if (argc != 2)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: server <port>\n";
      return 1;
    }

    boost::asio::io_context io_context;

    using namespace std; // For atoi.
    server s(io_context, atoi(argv[1]));

    io_context.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Client.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using std::placeholders::_1;
using std::placeholders::_2;

enum { max_length = 1024 };

class client
{
public:
  client(boost::asio::io_context& io_context,
      boost::asio::ssl::context& context,
      const tcp::resolver::results_type& endpoints)
    : socket_(io_context, context)
  {
    socket_.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_peer);
    socket_.set_verify_callback(
        std::bind(&client::verify_certificate, this, _1, _2));

    connect(endpoints);
  }

private:
  bool verify_certificate(bool preverified,
      boost::asio::ssl::verify_context& ctx)
  {
    // The verify callback can be used to check whether the certificate that is
    // being presented is valid for the peer. For example, RFC 2818 describes
    // the steps involved in doing this for HTTPS. Consult the OpenSSL
    // documentation for more details. Note that the callback is called once
    // for each certificate in the certificate chain, starting from the root
    // certificate authority.

    // In this example we will simply print the certificate's subject name.
    char subject_name[256];
    X509* cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(ctx.native_handle());
    X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), subject_name, 256);
    std::cout << "Verifying " << subject_name << "\n";

    return preverified;
  }

  void connect(const tcp::resolver::results_type& endpoints)
  {
    boost::asio::async_connect(socket_.lowest_layer(), endpoints,
        [this](const boost::system::error_code& error,
          const tcp::endpoint& /*endpoint*/)
        {
          if (!error)
          {
            handshake();
          }
          else
          {
            std::cout << "Connect failed: " << error.message() << "\n";
          }
        });
  }

  void handshake()
  {
    socket_.async_handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::client,
        [this](const boost::system::error_code& error)
        {
          if (!error)
          {
            send_request();
          }
          else
          {
            std::cout << "Handshake failed: " << error.message() << "\n";
          }
        });
  }

  void send_request()
  {
    std::cout << "Enter message: ";
    std::cin.getline(request_, max_length);
    size_t request_length = std::strlen(request_);

    boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
        boost::asio::buffer(request_, request_length),
        [this](const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t length)
        {
          if (!error)
          {
            receive_response(length);
          }
          else
          {
            std::cout << "Write failed: " << error.message() << "\n";
          }
        });
  }

  void receive_response(std::size_t length)
  {
    boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
        boost::asio::buffer(reply_, length),
        [this](const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t length)
        {
          if (!error)
          {
            std::cout << "Reply: ";
            std::cout.write(reply_, length);
            std::cout << "\n";
          }
          else
          {
            std::cout << "Read failed: " << error.message() << "\n";
          }
        });
  }

  boost::asio::ssl::stream<tcp::socket> socket_;
  char request_[max_length];
  char reply_[max_length];
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    if (argc != 3)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: client <host> <port>\n";
      return 1;
    }

    boost::asio::io_context io_context;

    tcp::resolver resolver(io_context);
    auto endpoints = resolver.resolve(argv[1], argv[2]);

    boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23);
    ctx.load_verify_file("server.crt");

    client c(io_context, ctx, endpoints);

    io_context.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Code for generating the certificates https://stackoverflow.com/a/8407739/7437667

If I run server and client on the same machine everything works. If I run server and client on different machines (wired network) I get the message **handshake failed: certificate verify failed**
I have tried both: generating the certificates on every machine and copying from one to other.

Comment: *"have tried both: generating the certificates on every machine and copying from one to other."* - given that you don't [explicitly set a trust file](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__context/load_verify_file/overload1.html) it will take some system defaults. If the issuer CA for your certificate is part of the system default is unknown, i.e. the details are missing on what exactly you did.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I think it is a problem with the keys. I have two different OSs: Ubuntu 18.04 and RHEL 8.2. Now I get the following mesages: ee key too small. After I fixed this problem I get the error message dh key too small. I hope an ubuntu update to version 20.04 fixes the problem

Comment: *"Now I get the following mesages: ... After I fixed this problem I get the error message ...."* - it is unclear what your doing since nothing what you are trying is reflected in the question. Also, don't make your question a moving target. If you google the specific error messages you'll find many question with answers here on SO.